# Automatically resize Flutter TextFormField content as the user is typing while keeping maxLines equal to 1

Tags: flutter, autosize, flutter-textformfield

I am using `TextFormField` in my Flutter app to get the email address of users. Some email addresses are long and so, if I keep typing, it will go out of the box. See how the first few letters of the email in the image below are outside the box.

[image]

Below is the code (just a simple `TextFormField`). I want the text to automatically resize while **remaining in one line** and also **I can see all the text**. Is there a way to do that?

```
SizedBox(
    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(407),
    height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(69),
    child: TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      autocorrect: false,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`auto_size_text_field`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field) package

```dart
AutoSizeTextField(
  controller: _textEditingController,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I just need to take care of validation outside this field then.